# Bridging gRPC over TCP to gRPC over UDS

Tags: envoyproxy, uds

I have a requirement to listen for gPPC request over TCP validate the auth token, then route the validated request to a gRPC service using a domain socket without any auth.

My initial research indicates that this could be be done using an Envoy proxy. Is this indeed possible, or am I barking up tbe wrong tree ?

Comment: I can't say if Envoy can do this exactly out-of-box, but depending on what you're trying to achieve, introducing Envoy might be an overkill.
I would recommend another approach. Since you're already dealing with gRPC, it should be pretty straightforward to create a gRPC app that does exactly what you want - listens on TCP, verifies some headers, and forwards requests to UDS. I can't speak for all languages, but that grpc-java now supports UDS out-of-box, just by using a target string `unix:///path/to/socket`.